# Find the smallest values that satisfy both equations.

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

How can find the values of x1-x7 that will give me smallest value for Z, while still satisfying equation 2?

Equation 1:
$$
Z = \frac{1}{x_1-75} + \frac{1}{x_2 - 75} + \frac{1}{x_3-75} + \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{x_4-75} + \frac{1}{x_5-37.5}\right) + \frac{1}{8}\left(\frac{1}{x_6-75} + \frac{1}{x_7-37.5}\right)
$$
Equation 2:
$$
x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6+x_7 = 1200
$$

Thanks

Comment: Are you supposed to know about Lagrange multipliers ?

Comment: I don't know about them. But I can learn about it,  if there is an example how i could use it for this kind of problem.

Comment: So, it is not the good time for that. Do not worry : sooner or later, you will learn about  and enjoy. Good luck in your studies. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks. Found a solution using minimize-on in wolfram alpha.